What is the suns movement in these verses?
in Quran 21:33 and Quran 36:40 the verses mention the day and the night and the sun and the moon in an orbit swimming.
What is meant by the sun not being able to overtake the moon? Does that mean the sun cant rise at night, or does it mean the sun cant collide with the moon?
And I already know the sun has its own orbit, but in these verses the way the day and night and sun and moons orbits are mentioned seems relative to each other and it wouldnt make sense that the suns orbit around the galaxy affects the day and night
Could the orbitting of the sun and moon mean from our perspectives? Like how we see the sun rise and set and the same with the moon? Or would this interpretation not work with the word "falak".
Also what is meant by the orbitting of the day and night? It seems to mean from our perspective so would the same apply for the sun and moon?
I'm really struggling to understand this and would really appreciate an explanation because this causes me a lot of doubts

First of all, sorry for saying this but if you doubt in the rightfulness of Quran by these verses, then those verses are not for you to struggle. As it appears from your question, you are a good believer, but also mention that Quran's verses are divided in two categories, those which are the firm ones, and those which are set to make doubts in some minds:

هُوَ الَّذِي أَنْزَلَ عَلَيْكَ الْكِتَابَ مِنْهُ آيَاتٌ مُحْكَمَاتٌ
هُنَّ أُمُّ الْكِتَابِ وَ أُخَرُ مُتَشَابِهَاتٌ فَأَمَّا الَّذِينَ فِي
قُلُوبِهِمْ زَيْغٌ فَيَتَّبِعُونَ مَا تَشَابَهَ مِنْهُ ابْتِغَاءَ
الْفِتْنَةِ وَ ابْتِغَاءَ تَأْوِيلِهِ وَ مَا يَعْلَمُ تَأْوِيلَهُ
إِلَّا اللَّهُ وَ الرَّاسِخُونَ فِي الْعِلْمِ يَقُولُونَ آمَنَّا بِهِ
كُلٌّ مِنْ عِنْدِ رَبِّنَا وَ مَا يَذَّكَّرُ إِلَّا أُولُوا
الْأَلْبَابِ [3:7]
it is He who has sent down to you, [O Muhammad], the Book; in it are
verses [that are] precise - they are the foundation of the Book - and
others unspecific. As for those in whose hearts is deviation [from
truth], they will follow that of it which is unspecific, seeking
discord and seeking an interpretation [suitable to them]. And no one
knows its [true] interpretation except Allah and those firm in
knowledge, [they] say, 'We believe in it. All [of it] is from our
Lord.' And no one will be reminded except those of understanding.

Those who have come to accept that Quran is rightfully and completely revealed by Allah, and Allah is the Creator of the whole universe and anything beyond the material universe, and that He knows anything and everything, and that what scientists discover --at best that their evidences and theories are not wrong-- will be what Allah has created, then instead of trying to frame Quran's verses into their present level of knowledge, they will try to understand Quran the way it is and upshift their level of knowledge and intuition so that the verses are no longer strange but rather intuitionally obvious; every apparent contradiction would be an invaluable opportunity to improve. For example Allah has stated that وَ هُوَ الَّذِي خَلَقَ السَّمَاوَاتِ وَ الْأَرْضَ فِي سِتَّةِ أَيَّامٍ translated into And it is He who created the heavens and the earth in six days. This doesn't mean that there was Earth and Sun and the Earth was revolving around its own axis of rotation so to justify the existence of the notion of day to then count the days from 1 to 6 and see how many hours, minutes, and seconds take it long for Allah to just create again the Earth and All the Heavens and Skies. Rather it means that day is a notion not necessarily defined by the Earth and Sun involved, but in this small portion of universe that we live and experience the concept can be reduced to such definitions. The same is when Allah AWJ talks about His hand يَدُ اللَّهِ فَوْقَ أَيْدِيهِمْ translated into The hand of Allah is over their hands, this doesn't mean that He has a hand like what we call hand, and His hand is over the other hands, but it means Hand near Allah has a meaning which if is to be reduced into our lives that would resemble ours, like power and alike ... If you want to check if Quran is really the words of Allah, then check that, after all it is the only miracle left from the past messengers of Allah, claimed to be all intact, so given that the miracles are proof for prophethood of the prophets, you should be able to understand that on your own. But if your heart reached the point that you saw Allah behind these words and recalled Him as your very kind and merciful creator and owner, then no longer doubt in His words if you didn't understand them and found them strange. These subtle words are indeed ladders for those who trust Allah being the all-knowing to improve their knowledge by traveling up the ladder, a guidance for those who believe. That is to say, the aspect of Quran being a miracle is for everyone, to hear that and think in that and be guided to the right path of believing in Allah, but the details are no longer for all, even not all believers will be guided and grow by a same verse or chapter equally. Muslims might be guided more and grow with different verses and chapters even in different sections of their lives. Quran is a book to live with, and not to study like studying a scientific book or paper, though it has all the science in it implicitly as well, but Allah will protect His words from anyone who is not ready to receive the message yet:

فَلَا أُقْسِمُ بِمَوَاقِعِ النُّجُومِ (۷۵) وَ إِنَّهُ لَقَسَمٌ لَوْ
تَعْلَمُونَ عَظِيمٌ (۷۶) إِنَّهُ لَقُرْآنٌ كَرِيمٌ (۷۷) فِي كِتَابٍ
مَكْنُونٍ (۷۸) لَا يَمَسُّهُ إِلَّا الْمُطَهَّرُونَ (۷۹) تَنْزِيلٌ
مِنْ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ (۸۰) أَفَبِهَذَا الْحَدِيثِ أَنْتُمْ
مُدْهِنُونَ (۸۱) وَ تَجْعَلُونَ رِزْقَكُمْ أَنَّكُمْ تُكَذِّبُونَ (۸۲)
Then I swear by the setting of the stars, (75) And indeed, it is an
oath - if you could know - [most] great. (76) Indeed, it is a noble
Qur'an (77) In a Register well-protected; (78) None touch it except
the purified. (79) [It is] a revelation from the Lord of the worlds.
(80) Then is it to this statement that you are indifferent (81) And
make [the thanks for] your provision that you deny [the Provider]?
(82)

